# How to use Azure Application Gateway's rewrite rules feature to rewrite the hostname of a website?

Tags: url-rewriting, azure-application-gateway, hostheaders

I have a website called `oldcompany.com`. Our product name changed, and I would like to use Azure Application Gateway in front of the website, in order to rewrite the URL, i.e. access the website using the `newcompany.com` hostname.

There is a feature of Azure Application Gateway, called *rewrite rules*, that allows to modify request and response headers, documented here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url.md#rewrite-http-headers-and-url-with-application-gateway. The reason I want to use this feature is that it allows specifying complex conditions to rewrite a header. So I don't want to be using the *Override with new host name* switch on the HTTP setting, but rather overwrite the `Host` header of all requests going through the application gateway.

I have defined:

- the listener to listen on HTTPS, port 443, hostname `newcompany.com`
- the backend pool pointing to `oldcompany.com`
- the rule binding the listener to the backend pool

With this configuration only, accessing `https://newcompany.com` results in Azure Application Gateway's 502 error page, which is expected, because the `Host` header in the request is still `newcompany.com`, which is not a virtual host recognized by the server (which is only serving requests for `oldcompany.com`).

So, in order to set the `Host` header, I have configured a rewrite ruleset associated to my routing rule. This ruleset has a rule that changes the request's `Host` header to `oldcompany.com`.

However, I still get the same 502 error page when accessing `https://newcompany.com`. I have pulled the request from my application gateway's access logs, and the request shows the following fields:

```
host_s: oldcompany.com
originalHost_s: newcompany.com
httpStatus_d: 502
```

which seems like the correct values for the original and rewritten hosts.

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Did you check that the Application Gateway successfully probes your backend? You may see the status on the "Backend Health" tab.

Comment: Yes, the application gateway's probe is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your configurations, you need to follow the next steps:

Add a backend.

Add a health probe.

Add backend settings and override with a specific domain name.

`By default, the Application Gateway sends the same HTTP host header to the backend as it receives from the client. If your backend application/service requires a specific host value, you can override it using this setting.`

Add a rule for the settings created above.